# Replacing WiringPi: how do I send on/off signals to 433MHz sockets with pigs?

Tags: pigpio, wiringpi

I have a 443 sender connected to my RPi3+.

I want to replace `WiringPi` to control my 433MHz sockets on my RPi3+.

I used so far the command `send 11111 2 0` with send from the `raspberry remote`package and `wiringpi` to switch off (that is the 0) the second socket.

I'd think, that should also be possible with `pigpio`'s `pigs`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Michael

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Why? wiringPi still works.

Comment: @joan Well, it is not available for bookworm. So, I coompiled it myself. But then the `send` command complained "No Hardwar line" in /proc/cpuinfo. And indeed that is not there. But anyway, `pigpio` should be more futreproof.

Comment: pigpio is unlikely to work on any Pi model after the 4.  The Pi5 (and I guess subsequent models) have a different GPIO architecture.

Comment: Ok... ut I am on RPi3+. Apart from bookworm, with bullseye it is avalailable. So I am wondering, how to trigger the sockets like with `send` from `raspberry remote` (https://github.com/xkonni/raspberry-remote; also very old...).